# Powershell object attribute not showing

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

Any idea why the $result.PathName doesn't work?

```
$results = Get-WMIObject -query "select * from Win32_Service where Name LIKE '%sql%'" | Select Name, PathName | Format-List
ForEach ($result in $results) {
    Write-Output "Test = " + $result.PathName
}        
Write-Output "done"
```

Expected output:

```
Test = C:\blah\blah.sqlserver.exe
Test = C:\blah\blah.sqlserver.exe
```

Actual output

```
Test =
+
Test = 
+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Format-*` cmdlets produce formatting instructions as output. This instructions not useful for anything except displaying result to user or for `Out-*` cmdlets. Remove `Format-List` from your code. And put expression after `Write-Output` in parentheses: `Write-Output ("Test = " + $result.PathName)`, to it be interpreted as single expression but not three different arguments to `Write-Output`. Or you can remove `Write-Output` entirely as it implied by default.

Comment: Thanks this is getting at the objects but producing this: <br/> `Test = @{Name=SQLWriter; PathName="C:\blah\sqlwriter.exe"}.PathName`

Comment: Did you write this: `"Test = $result.PathName"`? You should write this instead: `"Test = $($result.PathName)"`.

Comment: That got it, thanks. Any good site you recommend for picking up PS quickly? Is this site generally good for learning? http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/06/08/using-string-functions.aspx -- that page allowed me to get through the next part of my script

Comment: @Dird I mostly learned PowerShell by build-in documentation, MSDN, ILSpy to understand some internal working and practicing, so I can not recommend any good site for learning.

Comment: @Dird most people just pick it up "on the job" but I cannot recommend this book enough http://www.manning.com/payette2/. If you manage to find it it's a really good in depth read

Comment: I've found it but 1000 pages? goddamn >_<